# OS X 10.8.4 not showing updates - how to fix?

Tags: software-update

OS X 10.8.4 isn't showing any updates via the App Store or the command line softwareupdate tool. How can I make it start showing updates as usual again?

Edit:

`sudo softwareupdate -l` outputs "No new software available."

In Console, App Store logs

```
storeagent[205]: CKSoftwareMap: updateRequestBodyData:includeInstalledApps:includeBundledApps:conditionally:hadUnadoptedApps:waitUntilMapIsLoaded: timed out waiting for mdSemaphore
```

and softwareupdate logs

```
storeagent[205]: CKSoftwareMap: _expectedMetadataChangeTimeout: timed out waiting for mdSemaphore
```

install.log shows

```
Software Update[7145]: Failed Software Update - trust evaluation failed in SecTrustEvaluate with result: 3
Software Update[7145]: Can't load distribution from https://swdist.apple.com/content/downloads/60/30/041-5397/SPKMyGZ5qPWksQfvZHYwfhTRdB6HHsSjGn/041-5397.English.dist.gz: Host cert invalid or otherwise insecure download
```

Comment: Maybe because you don't *have* any updates? Can you be more specific as to what the problem is and how you are determining that a Mac is missing (or ignoring) updates instead of having all updates applied?

Comment: Are you in any kind of managed environment - ie a school or lab?  What is the output of `sudo profiles -P` ?

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes it didn't find the most recent security update, I had to manually get it from Apple once I was aware of it. I don't know how to be more specific; I'm pretty sure there was an update available, neither App Store nor `sudo softwareupdate -l` found it. That's all I know.

Comment: @da4 it's a personal computer -- "There are no configuration profiles installed"

Comment: @user53719, I mean like posting the output of `sudo softwareupdate -l`. If you read [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4262777?start=0&tstart=0), it details a similar problem as yours. Another option is to check `install.log` under `/var/log/`.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes checking the install.log led me right to the solution, I hadn't know about that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out Apple's swdist.apple.com domain uses a certificate from COMODO and that CA has been untrusted on this computer. Trusting it again worked but is distasteful[1].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodo_Group#2011_breach_incident

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on a reposado replica of Apple's SUS... turns out my webserver was missing the .dist text/xml MIME type.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps you took to fix the issue?